# Save array of images using matplotlib and pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an array of output images which I am displaying runtime one after the other. I want to save the images inside a folder named 'saved images'. The current code I made saves the images, the images are not saved separately as soon as image1 is generated and saved in image1.png image2 overwrites its location how do I avoid overwriting the previous image with new image

```
 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.savefig('image1.png')
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

Comment: without seeing the contents of `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`, it's possible that you are saving the wrong figure

Comment: More appropriate question would be how do I redirect the plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE) plt.imshow(image_np) to a folder as currently, it is displaying images on a console

Comment: @Stevens If the above comment is meant to be part of the question, please put it in the question (and explain what you would like to achieve and what you mean by "redirect"). As it stands, the answer given is correct, and to save an image, you call `plt.savefig("your_folder/your_file.png")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your images are saved as 'image1.png'. Instead use a variable to save images as different files like image1.png, image2.png, image3.png...

```
#initiate a variable
i = 0
for image in TEST_ARRAY_IMAGES:
  <your code as above>
  # save as image1.png, image2.png
  plt.savefig('image'+str(i)+'.png')
  # increment i
  i += 1
  <any code here>
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to add a bit of explanation to your code snippet in an answer to show the OP what you have done

Comment: it's saving the same image with multiple names with the above code for ex: image1.png, image2.png have the same image. More appropriate question would be how do I redirect the plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np) to a folder. Currently, it is displaying images on a console

Answer (score 0):

This works  :

```
i=0
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
      [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)

  plt.savefig('image'+str(i)+'.png')

  i+=1
```